# Upload path argument error on form.save()

Tags: python, django, upload, arguments

I'm trying fileuploads in Django - I'm having issues with saving a form with a file field in it. I have similar views to this that work absolutely fine, I don't understand why an error is being raised on this one.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

def view1(request):
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        ...
```

Then in my models.py

```
def upload_path(var1, var2, var3):
    return "{}/{}/{}/".format(var1, var2, var3)
```

Here's the traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /app/view1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Code\app\views.py", line 216, in view1
    form.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 463, in save
    self.instance.save()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 807, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 837, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 923, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 962, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1076, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1098, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1051, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1000, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 296, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 93, in save
    name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 327, in generate_filename
    filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)
TypeError: upload_path() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Can someone explain this error to me?
Thanks

EDIT

models.py

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    certno = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    datecreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to = upload_path("apple", "cherry", "grapefruit"), null = True, blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.certno)
```

forms.py

```
class PatForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Pat
        exclude = ['datecreated']
        labels = {
            'certno': _('Certificate Number'),
            'pdf': _('PDF'),
        }
```

Comment: Could you show your `forms.py`?

Comment: have you switched to a different version of Django?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with that `FileSystemStorage` instantiation, but it is not being used by your form and that isn't how you use it anyway. As the traceback shows, the error is being caused when your model itself tries to call the `upload_path` function because it is used in the `upload_to` attribute of the filefield.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was following a tutorial - https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html - I'm still trying to figure that out... :S

Comment: But you're not following that tutorial, you're mixing two completely different bits from there. When it moves on to using ModelForms, it no longer uses the storage class directly in the form.

Comment: Ah - rushed over it and made a mess of it. That's better. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `upload_path` function must accept 2 arguments `instance` and `filename`, but you have defined a custom function which takes 3 arguments, which happens to be strings.
You should change your `upload_path` function maybe more like this,

```
def upload_path(instance, filename):
    return "{}/{}".format(instance.certno, filename)
```

`upload_path` function or any function passed into `upload_to` option in a `FileField` is called whenever the model is saved, with definite arguments described as above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!